# Twillio call whispers and recordings

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I want to do the following in Twilio Studio:

I want an incoming call to be recorded and I want the person answering the call to hear a voice whisper - not the person calling. How do I set this up in Studio?

I'm not a coder and don't have a technical background. That's why I want to keep to the drag and drop features.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Studio doesn’t currently support the capability to handle whisper (playing a text to speech message or mp3 to the dialed party before connecting the calls together. You should be able
to do this with the Studio TwiML Redirect Widget and a TwiML Bin or Twilio Function providing the necessary TwiML.

The TwiML Number noun has a URL attribute which provides this whisper functionality.